# How can I cut an image at a 45 degree angle using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Basically I need to reduce the size of an image and cut it to be a triangle. How would I do this using javascript?

[image]

This is approximately what I am looking to accomplish (obviously it would be a straight line, but that's the best I could do in paint):

[image]

Here's the code I have so far: 
HTML: `<div id = "mydiv"></div>`
Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").onclick = moulding_change('5f52a13c425655fa62058418542b95ca');

function moulding_change(thumb)
{

var ppi = 15;

var SITE_URL = "http://www.asa.tframes.org:1881";

  var img = new Image();
  img.src =  SITE_URL + '/system/components/compimg/' + thumb + '/pattern';
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log("width before " + this.width);
    //width needs to be the same as the height (in this case 450)
    img.width = img.height / ppi;
    //img.width = img.height;
    img.height /= ppi;
    console.log("width after " + this.width);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.zIndex = 5;
    canvas.style.width = "1000px";
    canvas.style.height = "1000px";
      // Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
    ctx.save();

    // Create a shape, of some sort
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(img.width,0);
    ctx.lineTo(img.width,img.width);

    ctx.closePath();
    // Clip to the current path
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Undo the clipping
    ctx.restore();
    $("#mydiv").append(canvas);
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: using canvas is the way to go imho. It can be done with css but it'll be a pain up there

Comment: Why do you need this to be done in Javascript (in opposition to using CSS, or doing on the server-side)? Where does the image come from (user-uploaded, from the server, dynamically generated)? Do you need to save it afterwards, or is it just for display purposes?

Comment: I was thinking I need to use canvas, but I'm not sure how. This is done in javascript because my app is javascript. It is pulled from the server. I can't just cut the image beforehand because there are literally hundreds of these, so it has to be done dynamically. It is just for display purposes.

Comment: This may point you in the right direction http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-vector-masks-using-the-html5-canvas

Comment: I created a jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/allisonc/t9V8S/ but the problem is is that it is not showing the gold part of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Geoff, I was able to create canvas elements. The problem ended up being that I wasn't specifying a width, height for the image.